# How do I stay anonymous in the internet?

Tags: proxy, privacy

In the wake of international revolutions, many of which were partly organized on sites like Facebook and Twitter, I think it is important that all people find out how to become truly anonymous online...

For example, how can I get behind a proxy (or seven)?

I borrowed this question from AskReddit:
http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/f9fj1/how_do_i_get_behind_a_proxy_or_seven/

Comment: The best method is to turn your computer off.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have cookies enabled in your browser and/or you actually authenticate to any service, then you have lost your anonymity.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know that non-technical folk can get as anonymous as possible is to use the free TOR Project, which uses a series of volunteer proxies to route traffic so as to mask its origin.

You can get the TOR Project as a plugin to Firefox and use Firefox in Private Browsing mode to avoid leaving traces on the host computer and you can go even further and use a sandboxed browser, either through running your browser through Sandboxie or in a Virtual Machine, or you can get dedicated sandboxed browsers such as KACE that when run alongside TOR will give you a good chance of staying as anonymous as possible. It is very hard to remain completely anonymous.

Below are the links to all these goodies! :)

1. [TOR Bundled with Firefox](http://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)
2. [TOR Plugin standalone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtor/)
3. [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)
4. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)
5. [KACE Browser](http://www.kace.com/products/freetools/secure-browser/)

Answer (score 1):

I used the TOR project for a while, at that time it was a separate application and not browser plugin, the only problem was the unpleasant internet speed, from what the docs says your traffic is routed (onion-ring) through a series of proxies, haven't got to research why the speed was so bad. There is also another interesting project http://freenetproject.org/ I heard about.

Comment: The speed is bad, because you traffic is being routed through a series of proxies.  Some of the connections are likely being overloaded by people abusing the TOR network.

Answer (score 1):

For anonymity, you could start using [I2P](http://www.i2p2.de/).

Comment: i2p is going to be the future.  Support them.

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome and the TOR network when needed.

http://lifehacker.com/5614732/create-a-tor-button-in-chrome-for-on+demand-anonymous-browsing

Answer (score 0):

Also, liberte linux as a bootable thumb drive that runs everything through tor:

http://dee.su/liberte